# How to get associated data of a model using custom join cakephp2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp2 and trying to join two tables like this :

```
$employee=$this -> Employee ->find ('all',array(
'joins'=>array( 
array('table' => 'employee_histories', 'alias' => 'eh', 'type' => 'LEFT', 'foreignKey' => false, 
'conditions' => array('eh.emp_id= Employee.emp_id'))
),
'fields'=>'Employee.*,eh.*',
));
```

In EmployeeHistory model there is an association with table employee_designations like this :

```
public $belongsTo = array(

        'EmployeeDesignation' => array(
            'className' => 'EmployeeDesignation',
            'foreignKey' => '',
            'conditions' => 'EmployeeDesignation.designation_id=EmployeeHistory.designation_id',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
);
```

Now is it possible to get the EmployeeDesignation result in $employee array.

Comment: you may use recursive options with your find query.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the `employee_designations` table by adding another array to your `joins` array.  Something like this:

```
$employee= $this->Employee->find('all', array(
    'joins'=>array( 
        array(
            'table' => 'employee_histories', 
            'alias' => 'eh', 
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'foreignKey' => false, 
            'conditions' => array(
                'eh.emp_id= Employee.emp_id'
            )
        ),
        // array joining the employee designations table
        array(
            'table' => 'employee_designations',
            'alias' => 'ed',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'eh.designation_id = ed.designation_id'
            )
        )
    ),
    'fields'=>'Employee.*, eh.*, ed.*', // include ed fields
));
```